# How to retrieve data from a SQLite db in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, database, sqlite

I'm new to front-end/back-end communication and I was hoping for some guidance on the basic steps to retrieve data from a SQLite db file so that I can populate a page in my angular project. If you know of any resources I could read that would be of use, that would be great, but my knowledge on where/how to get started is zilch.

- If I have a SQLite db file, is it best to convert it to json first and then retrieve that file from Angular?
- Can I work directly with the SQLite db file in Angular and make use of the data that way?

TL;DR - Need to access data in a SQLite db file and display that in my Angular application, but I'm unsure of where to start/what the best practices would be to accomplish this task.

Comment: This should be a good starting point, https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to use database in browser directly using Angular, I think you need to relay on Browser support for that. I doubt if it allows you to use SQLLite on client side. [You can use SQLLite for sure in backend NodeJs app]

That being said, you can use  **indexedDB** specific APIs. If you want to easily integrate it with your angular app, I would suggest you to refer [dexie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dexie)

Hope this helps!